# Removing <script></script> block from returned html in C#

Tags: c#, html

I am returning html contents (page layout) in a variable but want to remove `<script>blabla</script>` tags and contents within these tags.

How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: It would appear that there is a view in the community that this is something which should not be attempted.

Comment: @flq The question doesn't ask "how do I do this using regex?", you could have just re-tagged the question and answered it.

Comment: Correct Dave, using regex for something like this may give unreliable results.

Comment: @justin it did, but it was edited away from me...

Answer (score 2):

You really need to parse the HTML.

Try using the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) which should make this pretty straightforward, for example:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("HTMLPage1.htm");
foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//script"))
{
    node.Remove();
}
```

Comment: By the way, parsing Html in general is a rather dicey proposition.  If you are working with a legacy web application (or a buggy one), then you might not get Html back in a form that Html Agility Pack can parse properly.